# Show one folder's content in other folder

Tags: linux, unix, symbolic-link

My question is about Linux. I have 2 folders - `/home/user/first` and `/home/user/second`. In the `/home/user/first` there are some files. The second folder is empty.

What I want to do is to have `/home/user/second` showing the content of the first folder. I tried using soft symlinks but all I achieved was having a shortcut to second folder in `/home/user/second` (so it was `/home/user/second/first` and the first was symlink to the first folder). I want first folder's content show directly in the second folder and the files should be linked (I mean deleting file in second folder automatically deletes files in the first folder).

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use bind mounts.  See `man mount` and search for bind.  You could have /etc/fstab set it up automatically with a line like

```
/home/user/second /home/user/first defaults bind 0 0
```

HTH